# Finding the limit of a complex function

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

> Calculate the limit, if possible $\lim_{z \to -3i} \frac{z^3-27i}{z+3i}$

My approach was initially to calculate the conjugate and simplify, but after
$$ \frac{(z-3i)^2(z^2+3iz+9i^2)}{z^2+9}$$ it can't be simplified further.

If I continue going on, I get
$$ \frac{0}{0}$$
which seems to be wrong.

I'm suspecting this limit don't exist, any tips?

Comment: Have you tried L'hopitals rule?

Comment: @user oh, I forgot it could also be applied for complex limits, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use the **L'Hopital rule**:
$$
\lim_{z \to -3i} \frac{z^3-27i}{z+3i}=\lim_{z \to -3i} \frac{(z^3-27i)^{'}}{(z+3i)^{'}}=\lim_{z \to -3i} \frac{3z^{2}}{1}=-27.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{z \to -3i} \frac{z^3-27i}{z+3i}=\lim_{z \to -3i} \frac{(z+3i)(z^2-3 i z-9 )}{z+3i}$$

Answer (score 2):

$-27i = 3^3\cdot i^3 = (3i)^3$

Now you have $z^3-27i=z^3+(3i)^3= (z+3i)(z^2+(3i)^2-3zi)$

Can you solve now?

Comment: I found very interesting this approach, I should have paid more attention to this simplification instead of using the "standart" method.